# Converting JAVASCRIPT to JQUERY to make the code shorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I manage to make the functions of our site work however it consists of 142 lines, now I'm trying to find a smarter way to shorten the lenght of my codes, to give you an overview here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4MaNy/

As you can see on the fiddle it is an event triggerred when a specific buttton is click
I have 6 buttons named as (CO1 to CO6), what I did is I made 6 times of the code below to make it work(you can see that in the fiddle).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    var shade = document.getElementById('shade');

    document.getElementById('CO1').onclick = function() {
        var src = "img2/Australia.jpg";
        var img = document.getElementById("placeholderImg");
        img.src = src;
        img.style.display = "inline";
        modal.style.display = shade.style.display = 'block';
    };



    document.getElementById('close2').onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = shade.style.display = 'none';
    };
</script>
```

Currently I am trying to convert them in Jquery using SWITCH Statements, but I can't get it into working.

I added a class name to my buttons which is ('.sbutton').

JQUERY CODE:

```
$('.sbutton').on('click', function () {
    switch (this.val()) {
        case 'CO1':
            var src = "img2/Australia.jpg";
            var img = document.getElementById("placeholderImg");
            img.src = src;
            img.style.display = "inline";
            modal.style.display = shade.style.display = 'block';
            break;
    }
        //and so forth
});
```

Comment: I am not sure 142 lines are the good reason to include heavy jQuery into your page...

Comment: To put this into perspective: The uncompressed jQuery file is `10337` lines long (`293,279` characters.) The compressed one is `4` lines long, but still `96,383` characters. There is no possible way to minimize a 114 line file to justify including jQuery.

Comment: Guys I think you are taking this quite literrally, I meant shorten the code in a smart way, would anyone prefer 6 <script type="text/javascript"> just to trigger an onclick button, what I'm trying to do is make a Jquery switch statement that would replace the 6 script tags, but its my fault mentioning the number of lines my bad sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `this.val()` inside of switch but you should use `this.value` or `$(this).val()` instead of it. `this` is an HTML object in your case.